# The for loop not processing

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I wrote this code

```
import java.util.*;

 // Compiler version JDK 11.0.2

 class Dcoder
 {
   public static void main(String args[])
   { 
     int small = 36;
     int big = 60;
     int remains = big % small;
     int ans =0;
    System.out.println("Small num-"+small+"big num-"+big);
    for(int a =0;remains==0;a++){
      big = small;
      small = remains;
      remains = big % small;
      ans=small;
        
    }
    System.out.println(ans);
   }
 }
```

And the for loop dose not process the console shows this
"**Small num-36big num-60**
**0**

**Process finished.** "

***Help***

Answer (score 0):

The loop:

```
     for(int a =0;remains==0;a++)
```

will repeat while `remains` is equal to 0, and will stop as soon as `remains` is no longer equal to 0.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

remains = 24 in the first run and when the loop checks for remains==0 it results in false. Thus nothing happens, try remains!=0 in loop condition.